# guava like java library for web development

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, web-applications, spring-mvc, guava

I'm searching a java library that provides high quality, well tested and absolutely basic classes that are very likely to be reimplemented in every (clean) web application. Examples are

- A paginator value class holding an offset and a limit
- Methods to get typed values from the request or a default value, e.g. *request.getInteger("limit", 50)*
- Wrapper around URLEncoder and URLDecoder for UTF-8 that do not throw
- Immutable tiny value classes for all components of a valid URL, parser and builder
- A clock interface and implementations to make time dependent code testable
- ... (I'll find more)

I know that Spring has a lot of useful stuff, but still lacks such simple things as those above.

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea, and look forward to you releasing the open source framework for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/). It does much of what you're after.

I've used it and would use it again.

Answer (score 0):

Evert project that I've ever been involved with had created tons of utilities like that internally.

Take a look at the source of many web frameworks and they are bound to have some util package or class (buy beware, it's for internal use mostly and they won't expect external code using it).

Some of the Apache Commons libs were originally build because of this, but they grew beyond simple utils and they are not always well maintained now.

Something that comes close now is OmniFaces, but it's specifically for JSF, while you are requesting, what? Plain Servlet, GWT and Spring MVC?